# MySQL query SELECT a.foo AS bar - Multiple?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1241

I have a query which I'm trying to group multiple table columns as "text", have a look at my query:

```
SELECT a.id as id, 
       a.name AS title, 
       (a.address1, a.address2, a.suburb, a.state, a.pcode) AS text, 
       a.suburb AS suburb
```

I get this error when trying to use it this way:

> 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Is what I'm trying to do impossible? Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd want to use the [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, CONCAT(a.address1, a.address2, etc...)
FROM ...
```

on other databases you'd accomplish it by using the `&` or `+` operators instead, but MySQL uses `concat()`.

Comment: The double pipe, "||", is the ANSI means of concatenating strings.